# How to make background video Responsive?

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to make the video background responsive. 
I don't want to embed a youtube video where it shows the play and stop bottoms. I just want the video to play naturally like it is a background. 
The problem is now it seems not to be fully responsive. I have set the width to 100% both in css and in html.

Here is one example of random site I found on internet which have responsive video as I'm trying to create http://www.mirumagency.com/hong-kong

```css
#header-video {
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#header-video .page-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
#header-video .page-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 42px;
}
#header-video .page-header small {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#header-video .page-header small:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#header-video:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 367px) {
  #header-video .full-height black-wrapper{
  max-width: 367px;
  }}
```

```html
<body>
 
 
 <!-- video header plugin & documentation here: http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/ -->


 <div id="header-video"
  class="full-height black-wrapper" 
  style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" 
  data-vide-bg="mp4: style/video/footage, webm: style/video/footage, ogv: style/video/footage, poster: img/front.png" 
  data-vide-options="position: 0% 50%">
 <!-- replace the above options with your own -->
  
  <div class="bar left-bar"></div>
  <div class="bar right-bar"></div>
  <div class="bar bottom-bar"></div>
 
  <!--<a id="down-link" href="#"><i class="icon-mouse"></i></a> -->
 
 </div>
 <!-- end the video header -->

</body>
</html>
```

chive: http://www.mirumagency.com/hong-kong

Comment: You might find the technique mentioned in this article useful - https://css-tricks.com/should-i-use-a-video-as-a-background/

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the link. It did not solved my problem, but could helpme further.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [FitVids.JS](http://fitvidsjs.com/). It may help you.